# error: Automatically removed objectClass from template as it is not defined in the schema

Tags: php, openldap

I'm installing openldap with phpldapadmin in 2 diffrent CENTOS 7 servers with configuration as follows:

**openldap server:**

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ldap
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=389/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
yum install -y openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers
slappasswd
```

set the pass and take note the hash

in: **/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif**

Change:

> olcSuffix: dc=**mydomain**,dc=com
>
> olcRootDN: cn=**user**,dc=**mydomain**,dc=com
>
> olcRootPW: **{SSHA}therandomhashfromslappswd**

in **/usr/share/openldap-servers/slapd.ldif**

Change:

> Line 134:  n=auth" read by
>
> dn.base="cn=**user**,dc=**mydomain**,dc=com" read by * none Line 144:
>
> olcSuffix: dc=**mydomain**,dc=com Line 145: olcRootDN:
>
> cn=**user**,dc=**mydomain**,dc=com

add:

> olcRootPW: **{SSHA}therandomhashfromslappswd**

in **/etc/openldap/ldap.conf**

change:

> BASE  dc=mydomain,dc=com
>
> URI   **ldap://hostname.domain.local**

Run:

```
slaptest -u
```

> config file testing succeeded

I receive checksum error as follow, but i ignore it.

> 54a39508 ldif_read_file: checksum error on
>   "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
>
> 54a39508 ldif_read_file: checksum error on
>   "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif"

Run:

```
systemctl enable slapd
systemctl start slapd
systemctl restart slapd
cd /etc/openldap/
vi base.ldif
```

create

> base.ldif

as follow:

```
dn: dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: mydomain.com
dc: mydomain

dn: ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: users

dn: ou=groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: group
```

finally run:

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=root,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -f base.ldif
systemctl restart slapd
```

**phpldapadmin Server:**

Run:

```
yum -y install httpd
firewall-cmd --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart httpd.service
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
yum -y install php php-mbstring php-pear php-ldap
systemctl restart httpd.service
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
yum --enablerepo=epel -y install phpldapadmin
setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap on
```

**result:**

connection is working fine, i can access phpldapadmin site and login through open ldap server.

**Problem:**

I receive a lot of errors: Automatically removed ObjectClass from template - while i actually need it to create acct, etc.

[image: I receive a lot of errors: Automatically removed ObjectClass from template]

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

I've been spent quite number of hours figuring out :(

Please let me know if someone can help me :)

Thanks,

AnD

Answer (score 2):

Those errors have no impact on the functionality.
You can hide those template error messages uncommenting this line in /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php:

```
$config->custom->appearance['hide_template_warning'] = true;
```

Comment: Added this configuration but they are still displayed for some reason :/

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems rather clear. `inetOrgPerson` isn't defined in your server's schema. It won't be there by default, and it doesn't look like you added it.

`inetOrgPerson` schema depends on `cosine` schema, which in turn depends on `core` schema. Core schema may be present by default.

```
ldapadd <auth for cn=config> -f /etc/openldap/schema/core.ldif
ldapadd <auth for cn=config> -f /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif
ldapadd <auth for cn=config> -f /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

You may have to hack a little in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` to be able to get write priviledges on `cn=config`. A number of distributions do not have reasonable defaults for OpenLDAP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes. that's part of the answer, i just found it a minute ago, but a couple things:


- how to solve: "template is not define in ObjectClass" ?
and
- where is CourierMailAccount, gidNumber, uidNumber, homeDirectory, displayName, SambaSAMAccount schema? it seems like not in the schema folder, how to find the .ldif and .schema file?